# Boostrap well class output off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have an issue with the output when it comes to well in Bootstrap. Sometimes the main header and the well output go off screen. When ever the user types something in the questions area he gets a response and that response the well class goes off screen in mobile view. As well as the header 1 text:

> Hello I am ZENYATTA!

The ZENYATTA text is cut out. Any way to make the input filed the output field and the header same size?

https://puu.sh/ud5C9/8eae3caf7a.JPG

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'},
  {text: 'What is your time?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Where I am located' + (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) + 'that is the day!'},
  {text: 'What language do you speak', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to me you speak: ' + language() + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (document.getElementById('address').innerHTML) + '!'},
  {text: 'You know you ip adress?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You ip adress is:' + (document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML) + '!'},
  {text: 'How many hours is it left until 0:00?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Left:' + (document.getElementById('count').innerHTML) + '!'},
{text: 'Current weather in Karlshamn?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => (document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML)}


 ];
 let ipinfoResponse;
 $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  ipinfoResponse = response;
}, "jsonp");

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 5000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').html(txt));
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});

function language () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLang
}
//location
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");


//timer
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#count').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);

//weather
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  $('.js-geolocation').show();
} else {
  $('.js-geolocation').hide();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  loadWeather('Karlshamn',''); //paramiter.
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = "<h2><i class='icon-"+weather.code+"'></i> "+weather.temp+"&deg;"+weather.units.temp+"</h2>";
      html += "<p>"+weather.city+", "+weather.region+"</p>";
      html += "<p"+weather.currently+"</p>";
      html += "<p>"+weather.alt.temp+"&deg;F</p>";

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #8dd8f8;
}

h1, p {

 text-align: center;
 color: #323330;
 font-size:  100px;
}

#output{
 max-width: 100%;
}
p {
 font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  padding: 45px 25px;
  font: 13px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  background: #1192d3;
}
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
     <img src="https://puu.sh/ud5Ub/c3598d2d3a.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ffc.gif" width="500px" height="500px">
    <h1 class="text-center">Hello I am ZENYATTA!</h1>

<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>

     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>


<div class="hide">
    <div id='ip'></div>
    <div id='address'></div>
    <div id="count"></div>
    <div id="weather"></div>
    <button class="js-geolocation" style="display: none;">Use Your Location</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'},
  {text: 'What is your time?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Where I am located' + (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) + 'that is the day!'},
  {text: 'What language do you speak', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to me you speak: ' + language() + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (document.getElementById('address').innerHTML) + '!'},
  {text: 'You know you ip adress?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You ip adress is:' + (document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML) + '!'},
  {text: 'How many hours is it left until 0:00?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Left:' + (document.getElementById('count').innerHTML) + '!'},
{text: 'Current weather in Karlshamn?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => (document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML)}


 ];
 let ipinfoResponse;
 $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  ipinfoResponse = response;
}, "jsonp");

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 5000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').html(txt));
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});

function language () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLang
}
//location
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");


//timer
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#count').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);

//weather
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  $('.js-geolocation').show();
} else {
  $('.js-geolocation').hide();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  loadWeather('Seattle',''); //paramiter.
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';  
      
      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #8dd8f8;
}

h1, p {

 text-align: center;
 color: #323330;
 font-size:  100px;
}

#output{
 max-width: 100%;
}
p {
 font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  padding: 45px 25px;
  font: 13px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  background: #1192d3;
}
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/monkeecreate/jquery.simpleWeather/master/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
     <img src="https://puu.sh/ud5Ub/c3598d2d3a.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ffc.gif" width="500px" height="500px">
    <h1 class="text-center">Hello I am ZENYATTA!</h1>

<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>

     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>


<div class="hide">
    <div id='ip'></div>
    <div id='address'></div>
    <div id="count"></div>
    <div id="weather"></div>
    <button class="js-geolocation" style="display: none;">Use Your Location</button>
</div>

</div>
```